# Why is Ansible registered variable undefined?

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple Ansible task module that does the following:

```
# Runs a couple of plays successfully...

- name: check if php-fastcgi process running
  shell: ps -eaf | grep php5-cgi | grep -v grep
  register: php-fastcgi-status
  ignore_errors: True
  changed_when: False

- debug: var=php-fastcgi-status.rc
- meta: end_play
```

When I run my playbook, I get the following error:

```
TASK [php: check if php-fastcgi process running] ********
ok: [myexample.com]

TASK [php: debug] ***********
ok: [myexample.com] => {
    "php-fastcgi-status.rc": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Yet if I log into the server and run the same command manually:

```
ps -eaf | grep php5-cgi | grep -v grep
```

... I see all the processes.  And if I do

```
echo $?
```

I get "0" as I would expect.  What am I doing wrong in my Ansible playbook?  I've been reading the Ansible docs and struggling with this for the last three hours and don't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your register variable name has invalid characters. Replace `-` with `_`.

```
register: php_fastcgi_status
```

From [What Makes A Valid Variable Name](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#what-makes-a-valid-variable-name)

> Variable names should be letters, numbers, and underscores. Variables
>   should always start with a letter.

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "php_fastcgi_status.rc": "0"
}
```

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you so much!